# How can I insert an array of figures in a beamer-class presentation?

Tags: beamer, floats, arrays

I want to insert an array containing figures in a beamer presentation. Is this possible?

If yes, is there an example for it?

I tried with side-to-side figures, but I'm getting a weird error message from this code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,15pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usetheme[blue,dark,colorblocks,tocinheader,]{tubs}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}

\begin{document}
\section{The Gem5 simulator}
\begin{frame}{The Gem5 simulator}
\begin{array}{ccc}
Fig 1 & Fig 2 & Fig 3 \\ 
Fig 4 & Fig 5 & Fig 6
\end{array} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**TUBS** : Template of the university

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It's certainly possible to arrange images in an array. But it would be helpful if we would know how exactly you want them to be arranges. Maybe draw a sketch? And show us what you tried to put side to side figures, maybe this can easily be debugged.

Comment: I edited the question to be more clear ... SORRY

Comment: Other than the fact that `array` is a math mode construct, and what you are after here is a `tabular`, I'm not sure I see an issue.

Comment: Forget about the array ... is there an alternative to place 6 figures : 3 on top and 3 on bottom

Answer (score 2):

I guess there could be multiple ways of putting array of figures inside a frame. 
The following three slides are basically shares the same simple idea. Note the `$` at the beginning and the end of `array`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\frame}{}{\justifying}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{arrary of figures}
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{array of figures tabular}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{The Gem5 simulator}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
$\begin{array}{ccc}
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-b} &
\includegraphics[width=0.33\linewidth]{example-image-c} \\
\end{array}$
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't need `\usepackage{graphicx}` with beamer, it already provides this functionality.